# Autocomplete in Fieldset

Tags: 7, forms, ajax

I have a form that has been working just fine.

There are two fields a Select field with a list of countries and a textfield for Towns for Autocomplete.

I decided to create a collapsible fieldset called ['returndetails'] to put these two fields in.

My problem I have seems to be with the function that returns the updated div after I select a country. If I use

```
return $form['returndetails']['return_officename'];
```

The autocomplete does not work and if I use

```
return $form['return_officename'];
```

The officename text field is removed.

Can anybody help?

Thanks
Simon

Comment: I think it should be just return $form. Why are you doing return $form['returndetails']['return_officename'];

Comment: I have tried that, but what I find is that the country drop down is duplicated each time I select a new country, so I end up with 2, then 3 then 4 country select fields. If you now how to change this behaviour that might sort out my issue.

Comment: can you share the complete form so it is easier to debug.